# Difference between authorize routes and authorize controller in gem Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, authorization

Can someone please tell me what the different between `authorize route` and `authorize controller` in gem `Devise` ?

Answer (score 0):

Full description is here 
open given link
[Rails Authorization](https://railsapps.github.io/rails-authorization.html)